# Is the difference between a Medusa's and a Bodak's passive gaze power intentional?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, designer-reasons

The specific difference I'm thinking about is this:

**Medusa**:

> Unless surprised, a creature can avert its eyes to avoid the saving throw at the start of its turn. If the creature does so, **it can't see the medusa until the start of its next turn**, when it can avert its eyes again.

**Bodak**:

> Unless surprised, a creature can avert its eyes to avoid the saving throw at the start of its turn. If the creature does so, **it has disadvantage on attack rolls against the bodak until the start of its next turn**.

The effect from looking away from the medusa appears steeper, since "can't see" includes an inability to target her with many spell and her getting advantage on attacks, among other things. It seems like the effect should be the same since you avoid looking at the creatures eyes in both cases.

Can anyone provide a **quote from the designers of the game** about whether this difference is intentional?

Comment: Mod reminder: speculative or logical-reasoning answers will be removed for being off topic, since the question is whether it *is* intentional, not what answer-writers think or can make a logical case for.

Comment: The game mechanics are the same, so I am confused as to what the issue is. If you can't see something it is essentially invisible to you (or you are blinded only with regards to it, take your pick) and you have disadvantage on attacks against targets you cannot see. So is this question only about the word choice by the developers?

Comment: @JonatanHedborg More specifically, why does one monster entry say you can't see it but the other details the penalties of it not being seen...?

Comment: @Slagmoth - the game mechanics are *not* the same: for example, a bodak can be a target for spells with the "that you can see" restriction, a medusa can't. Similarly, the medusa has advantage on attack rolls against you (because you can't see it) the bodak doesn't.

Comment: @DaleM I seriously doubt that they are intended to be different, if averting your eyes blinds you to one why not the other? I think way too much is read into this difference.

Comment: Answers not citing sources will continue to be deleted.  We're up to 8 now.

Comment: Because of the way that this question is worded I doubt it will get an answer. Most of the people who post answers on here seem to be such rabid fans of D&D if there was a quote from a designer it would be posted already. That being said there probably is a reason, since most of the relevant text seems to be a direct cut and paste, with the effect altered. If I were to hazard a guess, I would say they realized that the fact that you can't look at a creature is not the same as being blind to it, so they probably updated the text in volo's and assumed nobody would notice the difference.

Comment: @Duck that doesn't apply as Gauth, on Volo's, is worded exactly as Medusa.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I thought I read in meta somewhere we retired designer reason tags?

Comment: @Voromir [That’s (almost) right!](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/are-questions-about-rule-intent-on-topic) (Almost because it’s the question type made off topic, not the tag that’s retired.) However we also don’t make a practice of hunting questions after a change like that, so this being found open isn’t unusual. I’ve closed it now. For others, we’ll deal with them as they come up the front page or are noticed doing other things—like you have. You can always vote them closed or flag them as off topic.